# Azure Service Bus: Can't add rules to a subscription under Topics with partitioning enabled?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Service Bus topic with partitioning enabled. I can create a subscription programmatically under the topic, but when I try adding custom rules I get the following exception:

> "The operation is not supported for an entity with partitioning enabled."

My code is just using SubscriptionClient's AddRule method with using a RuleDefinition. Btw, I have no issues if the topic is not partitioned.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured out the issue. Basically, you can't create a rule for a subscription when the topic is partitioned.